# Analysis of sentences

Tags: sentence-patterns

Are both these sentences correct, and do they mean the same:

a) "Having lost my wallet, and being far away from home, I felt I had TO BEG people's kindess in order to return home."

b) "Having lost my wallet, and being far away from home, I felt I had TO APPEAL TO people's kindess in order to return home."

Comment: What makes you think one of them might not be correct?

Comment: They are both correct and I suggest the slight difference in meaning is less important than the strange repetition of "… away from home… return home…" in the same sentence.

Answer (score 0):

They are both correct, but not quite the same.

One of the meanings of **appeal** is defined by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/appeal) as

> **appeal**
>   VERB
>
> **1** Make a serious, urgent, or heartfelt request.
>   *police are appealing for information about the incident*

One of the similar meanings of **beg** is defined by [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/en/definition/beg) as

> **beg**
>   VERB
>
> **1** Ask someone earnestly or humbly for something.
>   *he begged their forgiveness*

But another meaning of **beg** is given as

> **2** Ask for food or money as charity.
>   *a young woman was begging in the street*

So your first sentence has overtones of **begging** from random strangers, or, asking for help *after* getting refusals to your **appeals** for help. You might **appeal** to someone's kindness, and if they won't help, then **beg** them to help you.

---

This WikiDiff page: [Beg vs Appeal - What's the difference?](https://wikidiff.com/appeal/beg) states the difference but I think it is wrong: their definition of **appeal** is strictly legal and overlooks this context.